# Polygons to Lines SQL Server 2008/2012

Tags: sql-server

Given a polygon (no multipolygons, or holes) what is the best way to explode it into lines using T-SQL. The end results is I need a record for each line that makes up the polygon.

Comment: Damn it - was so hoping there would be an answer here :(

Answer (score 2):

It's late answer, but better late than never.

I had same problem and solved it by using [STCurveN()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929182.aspx) for getting Nth line. But, this function doesn't work with polygons, so I converted polygon into LineString using [STBoundary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933985.aspx). Now, STCurveN() works great and you can do whatever you want with it.

```
geometry::STGeomFromWKB([WKBGeom],0).STBoundary().STCurveN(Index)
```

This is an example of using all of this. You can make loop, put counter instead of 'Index' and get all lines from polygon in a result set.